# Is there a better way to eval specific code as a method wrapper (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

This is sort of a follow up to a question I asked earlier today.  Now that I have it working, I am wondering if there is anything I should be concerned about.

My intent was to basically wrap some classes from a c++ library.
I know I could use Forwardable or one of the delagate classes, but I also wanted to try to use Rdoc and add hash arguments to quite a few of the methods in the various classes.

So here is basically what I have:

For each class I am wrapping I have methods like this.  the method_wrapper takes a string that is either the name of the class to call a class method on, or a string representation of the one and only instance variable to call an instance method on, and the name of the method to call.  It then does an eval to actually call the method.

```
 def initialize(*args)
    hash_keys = [ ]
    return_value = method_wrapper("Wvwaves::WvPointFilter", "new", hash_keys, args)
    @component = return_value
  end

  def add_point(*args)
    hash_keys = [ ]
    return_value = method_wrapper("@component", "addPoint", hash_keys, args)
  end
```

Here is the method_wrapper method.  The idea is I can add hash keyed arguments and rename the method to something more ruby like, and also add new methods and comments for rdoc.  I thought this was a good idea, because I only have this one function, method_wrapper, that I call for all the methods in all the classes.

```
  def method_wrapper(receiver, method, hash_keys,  args=[])
   if args.length == 0
      #puts "calling without args"
      return_value = eval "#{receiver}.send( :#{method.to_sym} )"
   else
      if args[0].class == Hash
        method_args = Array.new
        hash_args = args[0]
        hash_keys.each do |key|
          arg_value = hash_args[key]
          method_args << arg_value if arg_value
        end
        #puts "calling with hash args #{method_args}"
        return_value = eval "#{receiver}.send( :#{method.to_sym}, *method_args)"
      else
        #puts "calling with args"
        return_value = eval "#{receiver}.send( :#{method.to_sym}, *args)"
      end
    end
    return return_value
  end
end
```

Is anything particularly bad about this approach?

Comment: It would be helpful if you a title that is somehow representative of the content of the question.

Comment: sorry , yes that was kind of general, someone beat me to it

Comment: Isn't `eval "#{receiver}.send( :#{method.to_sym} *args)"` equivalent to `receiver.send(method, *args)`? Or is the `receiver` thingy misleading?

Comment: You have a simple typo in your code, `retrun_value` instead of `return_value`... That said, all your uses of `return_value` should be removed. They're all redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of the same method

```
 def method_wrapper(receiver, method, hash_keys,  args=[])
    return receiver.send(method.to_sym) if args.empty?
    method_args = args[0].is_a?(Hash) ? args[0].values.compact : args 
    return_value = receiver.send(method.to_sym, *method_args)
    return return_value
 end
```

P.S: Untested. There could be some syntax errors. But you will get the idea

Comment: this looks pretty good, I think the only problem I have is that in my method, I had hash_args = [ ].  The idea was i could place the keys that I would accept in the order the need to be passed to the target method.